# How to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1Y_2 \mid |U_1-U_2| <a\right]$ for $Y_i\sim N\left(\beta U_i, \sigma^2\right)$ and $U_i \sim Unif(0,1)$?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have that $U_1, U_2$ are iid $Unif(0,1)$ random variables and that

$$
Y_1\sim N\left(\beta U_1, \sigma^2\right)
$$

is a Normal random variable independent of another Normal random variable:

$$
Y_2\sim N\left(\beta U_2, \sigma^2\right)
$$

for a fixed $\sigma^2$.

I am wondering how to compute the conditional expectation:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1Y_2 \mid |U_1-U_2| <a\right]
$$

given that $Y_1, Y_2, U_1, U_2$ are all independent and that $a < \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you know that $U_1$, $U_2$, obtain the values $u_1$, $u_2$, respectively. Then, because of the independence of the variables,

$$
E[Y_1 Y_2 | U_1 = u_1, U_2 = u_2] = \beta^2 u_1 u_2.
$$

Therefore, we need to calculate

$$
    \int_{u_1 = 0}^1 \int_{u_2 = u_1}^{u_1 + a} \beta^2 u_1 u_2 
\text{d} u_2 \text{d} u_1
+
    \int_{u_2 = 0}^1 \int_{u_1 = u_2}^{u_2 + a} \beta^2 u_1 u_2 
\text{d} u_1 \text{d} u_2
$$

This can be simplified to

$$
    2 \beta^2 \int_{u_1 = 0}^1 u_1  \int_{u_2 = u_1}^{u_1 + a} u_2 
\text{d} u_2 \text{d} u_1,
$$

which is very easy to calculate.

Comment: Is the relation you have above explicitly conditional expectations? In other words, is the above equivalent to: 

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1 Y_2 | U_1 = u_1, U_2 = u_2\right]\mid |U_1-U_2| <a\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Y_1Y_2 \mid |U_1-U_2| < a\right]
$$?

Since you added in the observed $u_1, u_2$ values, is this conditional expectation form correct? Or would $u_1, u_2$ appear in the inequality as well?

Comment: @user321627 The relationship above *could* be viewed as what you wrote, but it is more natural (IMHO) to think of it as simple unconditional expectation over the region where the inequality holds.

Comment: Is there a formal way to understand what is going on? It seems like the expectation over the region where the inequality is appeared out of thin air. Is there a theory behind this? Like treating the $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1Y_2 \mid |U_1-U_2| < a\right]$ the same as $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_1Y_2 \mid \mathbb{1}\{|U_1-U_2| < a\}\right]$ where $\mathbb{1}\{|U_1-U_2| < a\}$ is the indicator?

Comment: @user321627 I'll update the answer to show it more formally (tomorrow, though).